# Sidebar Filter to mobile responsive help - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Good Morning all,

I was looking for some help.

Currently using the Blocksy Theme for my website:

(https://https://theurbanlightcompany.com/shop-2/)

The issue I cant seem to solve is that the left hand sidebar with the filter will not float at the top of the screen when it breaks to mobile view.

The plugin I am using for the filter is ‘Filter Everything‘.

Would anyone happen to know a quick CSS code I can add to my snippets? Or point me to some documentation on the right track?

Look forward to hearing from you.

Kindest Regards,
Mark

I have tried various amount of css code avaliable on the web but none have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile size filters are below content

**"will not float at the top of the screen"** - do you want to be sticky at the top when scrolling, like header (this is not ok because header has big height and one more sticky element will reduce view content size.

If you just want filters to place before content, and not after like it is now, solution is simple.

main grid has `aside` tag for filters (left part) and `section` for content (right part). `Aside` tag has the 'order: 1' and that is why filters are below content

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body #secondary, .woocommerce-page .has-one-sidebar > aside, body aside#mk-sidebar, .woocommerce-page #sidebar, .woocommerce-page .sidebar, body #main-sidebar-container #sidebar
    {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
        -webkit-order: 1;
        order: -1;
    }
}
```

You just have to override `order` property like this (need to be `-1` because `unset` will not do the job)

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body #secondary, .woocommerce-page .has-one-sidebar > aside, body aside#mk-sidebar, .woocommerce-page #sidebar, .woocommerce-page .sidebar, body #main-sidebar-container #sidebar
    {
        -webkit-order: -1 !important;
        order: -1 !important;
    }
}
```

You can place this `CSS` inside Customize section -> Custom CSS field (if theme support custom css) or if you want, you can make it like child theme.